# Conceptual doubts

Tags: sentence-construction, time

I'll do that an hour from now.

I'll do that an hour later.

I'll do that in an hour.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> I'll do that in an hour.

This is a common way to say this. If it is now 3:00, you will do that at 4:00. It is tied to the current time.

> I'll do that an hour from now.

means the same thing, but I don't think this is quite as natural sounding.

> I'll do that an hour later.

has no reference for the current time. It could be the same as the above examples, but also (let's say it is now 3:00):

> I have to go to the store at 6:00, so I'll do that an hour later.

which would be at 7:00.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all your sentences are grammatically correct. To be honest, one would have to be incredibly pedantic to discuss the differences in meaning. The differences in your given sentences are so subtle as to not be worth worrying about.

That said, to my ear, the first sentence

> I'll do that an hour from now.

has an air of patience about it, while the other sentences you provide have an air of impatience.

If I asked a child to wash the dishes and he did not want to do that, he would most likely respond

> I'll do that an hour later

as he doesn't want to do it so he's setting it off. But as I alluded to earlier, it is perfectly reasonable for the child to respond with the first sentence.

The take away is it doesn't really matter, but that the last two sound slightly more impatient.